# Starting an external process after opening a new tkinter window. [Python]

Tags: python, process, window, tkinter, external

I am working on a program that has a "Please wait while action is performed" window. This window needs to stay open while a batch file is run. The windows closes after the batch process completes. I am using the Python method .after() to call the batch process after the window has opened. The problem occurs that after the time set in .after() the window closes and reopens, goes white and doesn't display any text. Here is the relevant code.

```
   def backupCallBack(self, event):
      self.backupCB = Toplevel()
      self.backupCB.grab_set()
      self.backupCB.transient(self.exportGUI)

      message = "Please wait while the\ndatabase is backed up..."
      Label(self.backupCB, text=message, padx=100, pady=20).pack()

      event.after(200,self.runBackup)

   def runBackup(self):
      name = Entry.get(self.backupEntry)

      self.backupWindow.destroy()
      self.exportGUI.destroy()

      os.system('.\\src\\backup.bat %s' % name)

      self.backupCB.destroy()
```

The "please wait" window needs to open and remain open throughout the running of the batch process. Am I using .after() wrong? What would be a more appropriate way to accomplish this task? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `after` method is running `self.runBackup` after 200**ms** and that includes `self.backupCB.destroy()` which is your waiting window.
If your intention is waiting x amount of time before the window is destroyed,
you might consider moving `os.system('.\\src\\backup.bat %s' % name)`
into `backupCallBack` above the `after` method (and change 200 miliseconds to something more substantial).
Otherwise you will need to figure out how you can set a condition that is equivalent to:
`if batch == done`,